# Using list items as function arguments

Tags: python, function, paramiko

I am trying to use Python/paramiko to back up router configs. I wrote a function that works, but I want to read a CSV, split the lines and then pass the items in the list as strings as arguments into the function.

This is the code:

```
import datetime
import paramiko

def tftpbackup(tftphost,netdevice,hostname):
    date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
    sshuser = 'autobackup'
    sshpass = 'nmol#567'
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(netdevice, username= sshuser, password= sshpass)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("copy run tftp")
    stdin.write(tftphost+'\n')
    stdin.flush()
    stdin.write(hostname + '-cfg-' + date + '\n')
    print(hostname + '-cfg-' + date + '\n')



netdevices = open ("network devices.csv","r")

for line in netdevices:
    device = line.split(",")
    hostname = device[0]
    ipaddr = device[1]
    ipaddr.strip()
    hostname.strip()
    tftpbackup('10.20.17.21',ipaddr,hostname)
    print (ipaddr, hostname)

netdevices.close()
```

This is the CSV:

```
cclcoresw,10.200.17.2
ccl1stflrmdfsw01,10.200.17.3
ccl1stflrmdfsw02,10.200.17.4
ccl1stflrmdfsw03,10.200.17.5
ccl1stflrmdfsw04,10.200.17.14
ccl3rdflridfsw01,10.200.17.8
cclphdidfsw01,10.200.17.9
```

It fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\SITE-P~1\PYTHON~2\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py",              
 line 326, in RunScript
    exec(codeObject, __main__.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\Desktop\tftp backup.py", line 27, in <module>
    tftpbackup('10.20.17.21',ipaddr,hostname)
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\Desktop\tftp backup.py", line 10, in tftpbackup
    ssh.connect(netdevice, username= sshuser, password= sshpass)
  File "C:\Users\*redacted*\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-    
packages\paramiko\client.py", line 237, in connect
    for (family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr) in   
socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Anyone able to see where it is failing?

Comment: OP mentioned that function works, but not when it's from the CSV file

Comment: It was string formatting issue and asiviero's answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line includes the `\n` at the end of it, so your reading would result in IP `'10.200.17.2\n'` and so on.

Just change it to

```
netdevices = open ("network devices.csv","r")

for line in netdevices:
    device = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
    hostname = device[0]
    ipaddr = device[1]
    ipaddr.rstrip("\n")
    hostname.rstrip()
    tftpbackup('10.20.17.21',ipaddr,hostname)
    print (ipaddr, hostname)

netdevices.close()
```

So the `\n` gets removed.